# How to obtain the child process PID in C

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, pid

In order to get the PID of the child process I am doing this.

```
pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid==0){
  //child's work
}else{
  printf("The child's PID is %d",pid);
}
```

I want to print the child's `pid` from parent! So is it ok if I `printf` `pid` or do I need to use `getpid()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "fine?"  Did the code do what you wanted it to do?

Comment: I want to print the childs pid so this will print the childs pid or the parents??

Comment: The first match in [this Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+fork&oq=c+fork) answers your question completely and accurately.

Comment: @Rocket What does the documentation for `fork()` and `getpid()` say?

Comment: If called in the parent, `getpid` will return the pid of the parent.  Since you want the pid of the child, the best way to get it (in the parent) is as the value returned by `fork`.

Answer (score 1):

On success `fork` returns the `pid` of the child process, so `pid` will be the pid of the child process, So I'd say it's correct.

`getpid` is to get the pid of the current process, so it's not suited to get the child's pid.

Comment: I want to print childs pid from parent! so it ok if printf pid or I will need to use getpid()

Comment: @Rocket No, you don't need getpid, the way you have it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think this sums up the question :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        printf("In child => Own pid : %d\n", getpid());
        printf("In child => Parent's pid : %d\n", getppid());
    }
    else{
      printf("In Parent => Child's pid is %d\n", pid);
      printf("In Parent => Own pid : %d\n", getpid());
    }
    return 0;   
}
```